# problem calling balanceOf from another contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, ether, tokens

I try to learn solidity and i have a problem. I've created a base token and i want to call the balanceof method from this token in another contract. In Solidity Remix i get :

```
call to BaseTokenBet.getTokenBalance errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value.  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

My BaseToken :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

interface tokenRecipient { 
function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, 
 bytes calldata _extraData) external; 
 }

contract BaseToken {
// Public variables of the token
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals = 18;
// 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
uint256 public totalSupply;

// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify 
clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 
 value);

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify 
 clients
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, 
uint256 _value);

// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constructor function
 *
 * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of 
 the contract
 */
constructor() public {
    totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total 
    supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the 
    creator all initial tokens
    name = "BaseToken";                                   // Set the 
   name for display purposes
    symbol = "BASETOKEN";                               // Set the 
 symbol for display purposes
}

function getBalance() public pure returns (string memory){
   return  "some string";
}

/**
 * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != address(0x0));
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your 
    code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool 
 success) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) 
 public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check 
   allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your 
  behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address and notify
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your 
 behalf, and then ping the contract about it
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved 
  contract
 */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes memory 
 _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, address(this), 
   _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
 *
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender 
 has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the 
 sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens from other account
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of 
 `_from`.
 *
 * @param _from the address of the sender
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool 
 success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the 
 targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check 
    allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract 
     from the targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract 
    from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update 
    totalSupply
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
```

}

In my second contract i try to call balanceOf:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

import "./BaseToken.sol";

contract BaseTokenBet {

BaseToken public baseToken;

address public owner;

constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    baseToken = BaseToken(owner);
}

function getOwner() public view returns (address)  {
  return owner ;
}

function getBaseToken() public view returns (BaseToken)  {
  return baseToken ;
}


function getTokenBalance() public view returns (uint256){
    return baseToken.balanceOf(owner);
}

 }
```

When i call getTokenBalance i get the error posted above.

Can someone put on the right track with this?

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
baseToken = BaseToken(owner);
```

You are setting `baseToken` to point to a `BaseToken` contract at the address given by `owner`.

Needless to say, there is no `BaseToken` contract deployed at that address.

So to begin with, you need to change it to:

```
baseToken = new BaseToken();
```

Or to:

```
baseToken = BaseToken(someAddr);
```

Where `someAddr` is the address of an already deployed `BaseToken` contract.

You can, for example, pass `someAddr` to the constructor of the `BaseTokenBet` contract.

Comment: When i deploy my BaseToken the amount in the constructor is sent to the owner that created the contract (if i call directly the balanceOf method from Remix Ide with the current address i see the amount generated by the constructor). if i call new baseToken = new BaseToken(); will not this generate a new token contract everytime? The BaseToken will be deployed in advance. The address calling getTokenBalance should have already some tokens or should have 0 tokens.

Comment: @user978123: "to the owner who created the contract" - well, that owner is **NOT** the address that you pass in `baseToken = BaseToken(owner)`. That owner (`msg.sender`) is the contract which executes this statement (i.e., the `BaseTokenBet` instance).

Comment: Yes, i understand that owner is the one executing the contract. But also this is the owner that deployed the BaseToken contract. This owner has the supply of my BaseToken. If i call the method balanceOf from the deployed BaseToken passing the current's owner address i get the value of the supply. I want to get the same value, calling the balanceOf method from my second contract. Sorry for my noob questions.

Comment: @user978123: That will deploy a new `BaseToken` instance (whose owner will be your `BaseTokenBet` instance, as I mentioned in the previous comment). I am therefore guessing that you probably want to use the other option that I have suggested.

Comment: Tried second approach :  baseToken = new BaseToken(0xfd6681fffbedfe8bb69efdf62898dfabbf1ad406); browser/BaseTokenBet.sol:13:21: TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 1 arguments given but expected 0.
        baseToken = new BaseToken(0xfD6681fffBEDFE8bb69eFdf62898dfAbbF1Ad406);
                    ^-------------------------------------------------------^

Comment: @user978123: That's NOT the second approach! You cannot pass address to a newly created contract. Please read the answer again.

Comment: Yes, sorry it was baseToken = BaseToken(0xfd6681fffbedfe8bb69efdf62898dfabbf1ad406). Now all errors are gone, but the getTokenBalance for my address, where i know i have the tokens, returns 0.